# Snake lamps on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, animals, lighting, electricity

I have a pet snake that has two types of lamps. One lamp is turned on in the mornings (day lamp) and then the other is turned on at night (night lamp). They both are needed to produce light and heat for the snake. How can I operate this on Shabbos!?!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Can you [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/47934/edit) your question to make it less personal?  We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).  Hope to see you around!

Comment: Welcome Dallas, and thanks for your interesting question! You may want to consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 4):

Either

A) Get a pair of timers for the lamps

OR

B) Switch both lamps on before Shabbos and leave them on all Shabbos. Just point only one at the snake at a time.

Comment: My personal recommendation is to use timers.